# VB6 IDE Is Locking The Loaded Project's DLL

Tags: com, vb6, file-locking, binary-compatibility

I'm responsible for maintaining legacy VB6 code, and have encountered an annoying problem with regard to the locking of a project's COM DLL. (We'll call it **MyProject** and **MyProject.dll**)

When I load **MyProject** into the VB6 IDE, I am able to compile the resulting binary-compatible DLL **MyProject.dll**. I can then run my (Classic ASP) web application that hooks into the DLL (or anything else for that matter).

So, when I try to recompile the COM DLL, I get a 'permission denied' error. I then find myself having to carry out the following steps in order for the DLL to be unlocked:

1. Check I have no dependant projects open in other VB6 IDEs
2. Recycle IIS
3. Check the file isn't read only (sometimes it will be if I have checked it in to source control)
4. Close the project and reopen it.

Often it is the last step that fixes the issue, and allows me to recompile, which means that the VB6 IDE is actually locking the DLL of the loaded project!

My colleague explained to me that it was to do with the way a VB6 project works with binary compatibility upon the DLL, but was unable to suggest a resolution.

My searches elsewhere have yielded very little in the way of answers. Search queries that are related to this tend to return a lot of unrelated answers (maybe I'm asking the wrong thing of search engines).

The closest thing I could find on Stackoverflow was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419/unload-a-com-control-when-working-in-vb6-ide) from a couple of years ago, but it doesn't really fit the bill.

Does anyone have any other suggestions that might ameliorate this?

Comment: Have you tried killing the asp process (inetinfo)?

Comment: @GôTô - Recycling IIS does this. I know for a fact that the problem is with the VB6 environment

Comment: Are you sure about this?

Comment: It would be dllhost, and not inetinfo anyway, as the web app runs in an application pool with medium protection. Anyway, i am sure. The steps were really just to highlight the hassle I was having, not to ellicit queries on what was locking it. Just pretend there is no IIS, my question was really asking how I can stop the VB environment locking it. Thansk for your help, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep a copy of `MyProject.dll` named `MyProject.cmp` and point binary compatible setting to your .cmp file. This way you won't need reopening project file (step 4).

During check-in you can mark *keep checked-out* to skip step 3 too.

Comment: Yeah, that would work. Good idea. However, wouldn't this mess up the project environment a little for someone who hasn't created the copy as you suggested?

Comment: ...and as for the checkout - I do normally, but sometimes I forget! It was really just to highlight the hassle I have to go through to get the DLL to compile! :-)

Comment: +1 this is a good idea for several reasons and is recommended in the VB6 manual http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733706(v=VS.60).aspx @James The binary compatible settings are in the VBP, so everyone will be using the same settings. I'm assuming you keep the VBP file in source control? I'd recommend also keeping the `MyProject.cmp` in source control

Comment: Interesting idea.  Seems like it would solve the problem but may introduce another.  How do you keep the .cmp file updated?

Comment: Thanks to all. This is what I went for. It actually solves another problem for me when I have to change the interface in a development version. Pointing at the .cmp file actually helps maintain the compatibility until i want to ship, then I update the .cmp file.